# Настройка маршрутизации для 2 сетевых карт

Tags: сеть

Имеется 2 сетевые карты со следующими настройками:

Первая:

- **Ip** : 192.168.1.11
- **Маска**: 255.255.255.0
- **Шлюз**: 192.168.1.1
- **DNS**: 95.56.237.24

Вторая

- **Ip** : 10.10.20.244
- **Маска**: 255.255.255.0
- **Шлюз**: 10.10.20.10
- **DNS**: 172.16.0.24

При помощи первой осуществляется выход в интернет, вторая необходима для связи с другими компьютерами/устройствами в локальной сети

Как сделать так что бы на данном компьютере работал интернет и был доступ к другим компьютерам из *локалки*

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. Вы не сообщили какая у Вас ОС, то предположим Windows.

Открываем командную строку и последовательно выполняем следующие команды:

```
route ADD 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
route ADD 10.10.20.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.10.20.10
```

Первая команда устанавливает в качестве шлюза по умолчанию адрес `192.168.1.1`

Вторая команда говорит что все что адресовано в подсеть `10.10.20.0/24` следует пересылать на `10.10.20.10`

Проверяем корректность введенных настроек: например можно *пропинговать* какой то адрес в интернете, аналогично проверяем *локалку* если все работает то необходимо сделать данные маршруты постоянными, для этого необходимо либо удалить введенные маршруты при помощи команды `route delete @созданный ранее маршрут` либо просто перезагрузиться (маршруты пропадут после перезагрузки) и регистрируем их заново использую ключ `-p` т.е. `route -p add @Необходимый маршрут`

Comment: Спасибо огромное очень выручили. Хочется добавить, что командную строку надежнее запускать от имени администратора.

Comment: Прописывать маршрут 10.10.20.0/24 не имеет ни малейшего смысла - он локально достижим и не нуждается в шлюзах. А вот маршрут 10.0.0.0/8`->`10.10.20.10 я бы прописал, наверняка же в локалке есть еще подсети.