# две сетевые карты,как?

Tags: lan

Ввиду непреодолимых причин хочу поставить вторую сетевую карту для подключения напрямую по лан проводу к телевизору,а первая должна работать чисто с интернетом через модем(по автоматическому ip),это реально?если можно обьясните как настроить,ос 7-ка,заранее спасибо.

Comment: http://www.avesblog.ru/2011/08/windows-7.html или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/348828/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82

Comment: @labris А Вы точно уверены, что его телевизору необходим доступ в Инет?

Comment: @Akina я ни в чем не уверен, в приведенных ссылках ключи к настройкам.

Comment: Угу... к настройкам МАРШРУТИЗАЦИИ. Но не факт, что оно надо. Ладно, подождём уточнений от автора.

Comment: доступ к интернету не надо,кабель напрямую с сетевой в тв по лану